# AVX2 8x8 Float Matrix Multiply in Rust

Tags: rust, matrix, simd, sse

I'm interested in a fast 8x8 32-bit float matrix multiply in Rust, assuming availability of AVX2. After learning about the AVX2 intrinsics, here is what I came up with:

```rust
pub unsafe fn mm8_simd(c: &mut [f32], a: &[f32], b: &[f32], lda: usize, ldb: usize) {
    use std::arch::x86_64::*;
    let av0 = _mm256_loadu_ps(a.get_unchecked(0 * lda));
    let av1 = _mm256_loadu_ps(a.get_unchecked(1 * lda));
    let av2 = _mm256_loadu_ps(a.get_unchecked(2 * lda));
    let av3 = _mm256_loadu_ps(a.get_unchecked(3 * lda));
    let av4 = _mm256_loadu_ps(a.get_unchecked(4 * lda));
    let av5 = _mm256_loadu_ps(a.get_unchecked(5 * lda));
    let av6 = _mm256_loadu_ps(a.get_unchecked(6 * lda));
    let av7 = _mm256_loadu_ps(a.get_unchecked(7 * lda));
    let mut cv0 = _mm256_loadu_ps(c.get_unchecked_mut(0 * ldb));
    let mut cv1 = _mm256_loadu_ps(c.get_unchecked_mut(1 * ldb));
    let mut cv2 = _mm256_loadu_ps(c.get_unchecked_mut(2 * ldb));
    let mut cv3 = _mm256_loadu_ps(c.get_unchecked_mut(3 * ldb));
    let mut cv4 = _mm256_loadu_ps(c.get_unchecked_mut(4 * ldb));
    let mut cv5 = _mm256_loadu_ps(c.get_unchecked_mut(5 * ldb));
    let mut cv6 = _mm256_loadu_ps(c.get_unchecked_mut(6 * ldb));
    let mut cv7 = _mm256_loadu_ps(c.get_unchecked_mut(7 * ldb));
    let mut mask = _mm256_setzero_si256();
    for k in 0..8 {
        let bv = _mm256_loadu_ps(b.get_unchecked(k * ldb));
        cv0 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(_mm256_permutevar8x32_ps(av0, mask), bv, cv0);
        cv1 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(_mm256_permutevar8x32_ps(av1, mask), bv, cv1);
        cv2 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(_mm256_permutevar8x32_ps(av2, mask), bv, cv2);
        cv3 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(_mm256_permutevar8x32_ps(av3, mask), bv, cv3);
        cv4 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(_mm256_permutevar8x32_ps(av4, mask), bv, cv4);
        cv5 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(_mm256_permutevar8x32_ps(av5, mask), bv, cv5);
        cv6 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(_mm256_permutevar8x32_ps(av6, mask), bv, cv6);
        cv7 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(_mm256_permutevar8x32_ps(av7, mask), bv, cv7);
        mask = _mm256_add_epi32(mask, _mm256_set1_epi32(1));
    }
    _mm256_storeu_ps(c.get_unchecked_mut(0 * ldb), cv0);
    _mm256_storeu_ps(c.get_unchecked_mut(1 * ldb), cv1);
    _mm256_storeu_ps(c.get_unchecked_mut(2 * ldb), cv2);
    _mm256_storeu_ps(c.get_unchecked_mut(3 * ldb), cv3);
    _mm256_storeu_ps(c.get_unchecked_mut(4 * ldb), cv4);
    _mm256_storeu_ps(c.get_unchecked_mut(5 * ldb), cv5);
    _mm256_storeu_ps(c.get_unchecked_mut(6 * ldb), cv6);
    _mm256_storeu_ps(c.get_unchecked_mut(7 * ldb), cv7);
}
```

I load the A and C matrices into 256-bit variables to begin with, and multiply thorugh, loading each vector of B once. So, I think I've optimized the number of memory accesses.

Because I multiply a column of A with a row of B at a time, I use `mask` with `_mm256_permutevar8x32_ps` to pull out one float at a time from A, broadcast it across a 256-bit variable to multiply with B. The results are accumulated through the loop.

Interestingly, on my machine which supports AVX512, the compiler optimizes away the memory caching and permute intrinsics and [generates a function](https://godbolt.org/z/Mq7hxch8z) almost of purely unrolled `vfmadd***ps` intructions. I found this quite interesting.

What are the opportunities to make this faster?

Answer (score 5):

> Because I multiply a column of A with a row of B at a time, I use mask with `_mm256_permutevar8x32_ps` to pull out one float at a time from A

But the compiler has undone that, at least in the context that you showed it in, using `vbroadcastss` on each entry individually.

Which is probably the right idea, since loads are cheaper than permutes on a bunch of processors, and a broadcast-from-memory doesn't count as a permute (unlike broadcasting from a register). For example Alder Lake can do 3 loads per cycle (with broadcast), but only one `vpermps`. Many Intel processors can do more loads per cycle than permutes. But on for example Zen4, loads and permutes both have a throughput of 2 per cycle.

You can write the broadcast-load yourself too, using `_mm256_broadcast_ss` or `_mm256_set1_ps` whichever you like best. But that wouldn't change anything, at least not for this function by itself, maybe if the function is inlined into a context where `A` is in registers it may result in different code.

I don't have anything really to suggest, the usual techniques for larger matrices don't apply, and there's already plenty of opportunity for instruction-level parallelism for the FMAs.

Comment: Thanks for the insight on permute/load/broadcast. I have another version where I use `cv0 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(_mm256_broadcast_ss(a.get_unchecked(0 * lda + k)), bv, cv0);` and it turns out the compiler outputs the same assembly as the one above.